# Widget is disposed when trying to remove Objects from TableViewer

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I have a listener class with a `TableViewer` and calls `remove(Object)` to remove rows in a table.  Code is using `Display.getDefault().syncExec` but still seems there is some synchronization issue.  Also this does not happen all the time and for some reason only happens in Windows 7 and not in Windows XP.  We tried to put a check on the `TableViewer.getTable().isDisposed()` before removing the Object and still we are getting the "Widget is disposed" error.

Does anyone have any ideas how to prevent this?  We are using jface-3.2.0.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:822)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:798)
    at com.sdm.hw.client.swt.HwMain.main(HwMain.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.getData(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer.doFindItem(TableViewer.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.findItems(StructuredViewer.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.findItem(StructuredViewer.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer.setSelectionToWidget(TableViewer.java:1138)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelectionToWidget(StructuredViewer.java:1619)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1330)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer.remove(TableViewer.java:993)
```

Comment: That is a very old version of JFace. Show us your code doing the `isDisposed` check and the `syncExec`.

Comment: Since you're using a Viewer, you should be manipulating your underlying model and refreshing the viewer instead of talking to the widgets directly.